# Select all elements from a table, and check if they match to another table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, phpmyadmin

I have two tables, and I want to take all entities from the first table, then, check if they can be related to a specific entity from another table. If they can be related the database returns 1 (or true), else it returns NULL (or false).

[image: Aïe]

I tried some things with LEFT JOIN but none of them work. I think the solution is simple but I can't figure it out...

**Context :** In my application I make two requests, the first one take all entities from oneTable, the second one take all idOT from anotherTable where idAT is equal to 2, THEN, I make a loop where I save all entities from the first request and in this loop I make another loop where I check if the current element is present on the second request. I thought they this solution was to heavy (two requests and imbricated loops) so I tried to do it directly in one request.

Thank you for your help guys ! I hope it won't make you lose your time...

**Edit :** @Strawberry gave me the answer in the comments, I was doing

```
SELECT * FROM oneTable LEFT JOIN anotherTable ON oneTable.idOT = anotherTable.idOT **WHERE** anotherTable.idAT = 2
```

instead of

```
SELECT * FROM oneTable LEFT JOIN anotherTable ON oneTable.idOT = anotherTable.idOT **AND** anotherTable.idAT = 2
```

It's as simple as that... Thank you again guys.

Comment: maybe this will help: http://lh5.ggpht.com/-fnOQYPFr8D0/UagAzBIgMvI/AAAAAAAABbo/3fBL5Fm3Y9Y/SQL%252520JOINs.jpg

Comment: Can we see your attempt at a LEFT JOIN? And if we cared about losing time, we probably wouldn't be here ;-)

Comment: something like that : SELECT * FROM oneTable LEFT JOIN anotherTable ON oneTable.idOT = anotherTable.idOT WHERE anotherTable.idAT = 2. But I need all entity from oneTable...

Comment: Thank you @Strawberry I knew it was simple (I thought I had already try this but apparently not^^). Thank you Andrew too for you help. I feel so noob...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank to the comments of the question the correct request is :

```
SELECT * FROM oneTable
LEFT JOIN anotherTable ON oneTable.idOT = anotherTable.idOT
AND anotherTable.idAT = 2;
```